# rhino python script move object

Tags: python, rhino3d

i'm going to script a code to get 2 dimension and draw a rectangel
then repeat that u-times by rotating and moving it.and present all rectangels..
i've wrote this:

```
 #start
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
#set the work plane
plane = rs.WorldXYPlane()
#draw a rectangel 
a=rs.AddRectangle( plane, x, y )

#set a module to repeat rectangels 
c=[]
for i in range(u):
    plane = rs.RotatePlane(plane, i+2.0, [0,0,1])
    c=c.append(rs.AddRectangle(plane, x, y ))
    d=rs.MoveObject(c[i],(0,0,1))
```

it declare this error:

```
Runtime error (TypeErrorException): 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Traceback:
  line 13, in script
```

how i can fix it?

Comment: `c.append` returns `None`. You don't need to reassign `c`, calling append should mutate the existing list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from `c=c.append(rs.AddRectangle(plane, x, y ))` As @byxor commented, and should simply be `c.append(rs.AddRectangle(plane, x, y ))`

There are several other issues with the code that may cause side effects based on your stated goal.

1. `a=rs.AddRectangle( plane, x, y )` is assigned but not used. If you are scripting in grasshopper and using `a` as the default output, you will only get a single rect as a result.
2. `plane = rs.RotatePlane(plane, i+2.0, [0,0,1])` is re-using `plane` so you will get a double increment with `i+2.0` (prior rotation plus new rotation). This is not necessarily wrong, but a bit less intuitive than `i*2`.
3. `d=rs.MoveObject(c[i],(0,0,1))` moves your item, but `d` is not returned and is overwritten by the next iteration. Also, you are moving all items to the same location and if you want increasing movement, you need an incrementor like `(0,0,1*i)`.

Bellow is an example that is a bit more clear, and assumes `X`,`Y` are `float` and `U` is a `int` with `a` the grasshopper script component output.

### **Working Example:**

```py
#Imports.
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

#Set the work plane.
plane = rs.WorldXYPlane()

#Create Output Array. 
c=[]

#Create rectangles.
for i in range(u):
    #Rotate by increasing increments
    newPlane = rs.RotatePlane(plane, i*2.0, [0,0,1])
    #Create rectangle.
    rect = rs.AddRectangle(newPlane, x, y )
    #Move rectange by increasing increments.
    rs.MoveObject(rect,(0,0,1*i))
    #Add final rectangle to output list.
    c.append(rect)

#Return final List.
a = c
```

Comment: hello dear @byxor .thank you for your complete attention. I wrote it on grasshopper and x,y,u had number sliders and (a) was  the output. anyway I found the answer and in addition i rotate rectangels insted of their planes...